# How to solve an indefinite integral of this form?

Tags: integration

I have these two integrals. $$\int \frac{x^3}{(x^4+1)^{3/2}} dx$$$$\int x^2 (x^3+2)^{5/2} dx$$ I'm wondering how I can solve them. In the first one I place the $(x^4+1)$ in $dx$, so it becomes $d(x^4+1)$ and then I multiply everything by $1/4.$ But after that I get stuck and I don't know what to do with the $x^3$ and the $x^2$. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You are kinda there. Note that $d(x^4 + 1) = 4x^3$ so doing that will take care of the $x^3$ and you will be left with a standard integral. Same holds for the second case.

Comment: @sudeep5221 thanks this helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute $u = x^4+1$, then $du/dx = 4x^3$, so "multiplying by $dx$" gives $du = 4x^3dx$. Then $$\int \frac{x^3}{(x^4+1)^{5/2}} dx = \frac{1}{4} \int \frac{4x^3}{(x^4+1)^{5/2}} dx = \frac 1 4 \int \frac{1}{u^{5/2}}du = \frac 1 4 \cdot \frac{-2}{3} \frac{1}{u^{3/2}}$$ Substituting back we get $$\frac 1 4 \cdot \frac{-2}{3} \frac{1}{u^{3/2}} = -\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{(x^4+1)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

First integral: substitute $t=x^4+1.$

Second integral: substitute $t=x^3+2.$

Answer (score 0):

For the first, put
$$x^2=\sinh(t), 2xdx=\cosh(t)dt$$

$$(x^4+1)^\frac 32=\cosh^3(t)$$